# Set another value while binding path value is null in textblock

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

i have a textblock, in my source 2 property for display name in text-block 
Property1 is null then display Property2

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Property1 , Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DataConvertor}, ConverterParameter=lblDisplayName,TargetNullValue={Binding Path=Property ,Mode=OneWay}}"></TextBlock>
```

but it's give me error while running

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am got the answer but in a different way

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding  Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DataConvertor}, ConverterParameter=lblName}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" ></TextBlock>
```

i am not assign any particular property for binding and assign value from converter

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this code,it is difficult to say what you are trying to do here.

But I would suggest you to handle this is your **ViewModel**.

```
    private string _property1;
    public string Property1
    {
            get{
                return _property1;
            }
            set
            {
                Property1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Property1");
            }
    }

    private string _property2;
    public string Property2
    {
            get{
                return _property2;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value!=null)
                {
                    Property2 = value;
                }else
                {
                    Property2 = Property1;
                }                   
                OnPropertyChanged("Property2");
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think use converter class ans assign a second property instead of changing property value